# How to convert strings in python to vectors of numbers so i can compare them to other vectors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, vector

I am looking for a way to convert Strings into vectors of numbers in phyton. 
Like

> "Hi how are you?" -> "29 73 281 38"
>        "How are you doing" -> "73 281 28 54"

I want to compare sentences from a user input to sentences out of a databese, which are stored as vectors.

Comment: Please be more specific. I don’t see any vectors in there, nor an explanation of how the “conversion” should be done. Can you expand on the database aspect? This might be a case of the XY Problem. As it stands this question is completely unclear.

Comment: Take a look at [`Tokenizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to create a **dense vector** representation for your input sentences.

See if below code helps.

```
sentences = ["Hi how are you?", "How are you doing"]

# Step 1: Create vocabulary - a set of distinct tokens from your input sentences 
vocab = set()
for sentence in sentences:
    tokens = sentence.split()
    for token in tokens:
        vocab.add(token)

# Step 2: Create a map (token: ID)
vocab_map = {}
for i, token in enumerate(sorted(vocab)): # sorted lexicographically for reproducibility 
    vocab_map[token] = i

# encode the sentences using the map you created in the previous step
for sentence in sentences:
    encoded_sentence = []
    tokens = sentence.split()
    for token in tokens:
        encoded_sentence.append(str(vocab_map[token]))
    print(' '.join(encoded_sentence))
```

Running the above code should get output the following:

```
0 4 2 6
1 2 5 3
```